# Replace NA with other row value based on id

Tags: r, spss

I would like to replace NA with value from other rows based on ID.
I've found similar questions but I not found solution for my problem.

Below part of table

```
   XCODE Age Sex ResultA ResultB ResultC
1   X001  12   2       2       3       4
2   X002  23   2       4       6      66
3   X003  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
4   X004  32   1       1       7       3
5   X005  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
6   X001  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
7   X002  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
8   X003  33   1       8       7       6
9   X004  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
10  X005  55   2       8       8       8
```

I have SPSS file with over 6000 columns.

I used

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset)[, Age:= Age[!is.na(Age)][1L] , by = XCODE]
```

but this is good only for single column and I need deal with many columns.

So how can I execute code above on all columns?

Comment: It's easier to answer if you provide reproducible data and show another table which shows how you want it to be.

Comment: So there is always exactly one non-`NA` value and one (or more?) `NA` per group, right?

Comment: Why the SPSS tag - are you looking for an answer in SPSS too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` we can select the columns which we want to `replace`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (2:ncol(df)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
            replace(x, is.na(x), x[!is.na(x)][1])) , XCODE]

df
#    XCODE Age Sex ResultA ResultB ResultC
# 1:  X001  12   2       2       3       4
# 2:  X002  23   2       4       6      66
# 3:  X003  33   1       8       7       6
# 4:  X004  32   1       1       7       3
# 5:  X005  55   2       8       8       8
# 6:  X001  12   2       2       3       4
# 7:  X002  23   2       4       6      66
# 8:  X003  33   1       8       7       6
# 9:  X004  32   1       1       7       3
#10:  X005  55   2       8       8       8
```

---

Using the same logic in `dplyr` we can replace `NA`s with first non-NA value of the group for all columns

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(XCODE) %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), .[!is.na(.)][1]))


#  XCODE   Age   Sex ResultA ResultB ResultC
#   <fct> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1 X001     12     2       2       3       4
# 2 X002     23     2       4       6      66
# 3 X003     33     1       8       7       6
# 4 X004     32     1       1       7       3
# 5 X005     55     2       8       8       8
# 6 X001     12     2       2       3       4
# 7 X002     23     2       4       6      66
# 8 X003     33     1       8       7       6
# 9 X004     32     1       1       7       3
#10 X005     55     2       8       8       8
```

Or only selected columns

```
cols <- c("Age", "Sex", "ResultA","ResultB")
df %>%
  group_by(XCODE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(cols), ~ replace(., is.na(.), .[!is.na(.)][1]))
```

---

Comment: i used ```setDT(df)[, (2:ncol(df)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
            replace(x, is.na(x), x[!is.na(x)][1])) , XCODE]```, and it works great ! 
But now I would like to remove duplicates and leave only one of each XCODE example. Is there such function which i could use with data.table?

Comment: @l2archer by one do you mean the first one of each `XCODE` ? You can try doing `df[!duplicated(df$XCODE), ]` after the above operation.

Comment: But how then save that result to data.table, so I could later export to .xlss? Now im using `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
library(WriteXLS)
WriteXLS("dataset",ExcelFileName="D:/XCodeMerged50.xlsx",row.names=F,col.names=T)`

Comment: `df1 <- df[!duplicated(df$XCODE), ]` and then you can `xlsx::write.xlsx(x = df1, file = "your.excelfile.xlsx",sheetName = "test")` or just use `write.csv(df1, "test.csv")`

Comment: Just one thing remains to solve. My data table based on SPSS file which has many labels for variables. And now I have labeled values e.g. in cell there is information education level - High school. And i would prefer to receive raw value (number of label). How to change coding of values in table to receive raw, not labeled value?

Comment: Umm..it is not clear to me. However, I would suggest you to ask a new question as every post should solve only one specific problem. You might get good answers on the new post.

Answer (score 0):

We can group by `XCODE` and use `fill()` to fill in NAs with latest non-NA. In this case we need to fill in both directions. Also note that since you are filling up all variables, then the function `everything()` can be used

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(XCODE) %>% 
 fill(everything()) %>% 
 fill(everything(), .direction = 'up')
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 6
> # Groups:   XCODE [5]
>    XCODE   Age   Sex ResultA ResultB ResultC
>    <fct> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
>  1 X001     12     2       2       3       4
>  2 X001     12     2       2       3       4
>  3 X002     23     2       4       6      66
>  4 X002     23     2       4       6      66
>  5 X003     33     1       8       7       6
>  6 X003     33     1       8       7       6
>  7 X004     32     1       1       7       3
>  8 X004     32     1       1       7       3
>  9 X005     55     2       8       8       8
> 10 X005     55     2       8       8       8
> ```